# Regex: match string with parathese with '|' operator

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match a substring of "Number" or "Number(s)" in a string using a single Regex. However, I can get them to match individually, but not together.

Individually,
`'Number'` can match the word `number`

`'Number[(]s[)]'` can match `Number(s)`.

However, if I put them together and do `"Number|Number[(]s[)]"` it is not matching for `(s)` of `"Number(s)"`.

What I have tried:

1: Put `\b` boundary around the second string, doesn't work.

2: Use `\` to escape, but C# yells at me for unrecognized escape sequence, so I opted out of this option

I know that I can use two regex to do what I want, but I wanted to understand what is wrong here and learn.

Comment: Use `@"Number(?:\(s\))?"`, an optional group. If you still want the `|` way, put the longer one first, `Number[(]s[)]|Number`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Number|Number[(]s[)]` wont match `Number(s)` because it's first part "Number" matches it.
Try change the pattern part order: `Number[(]s[)]|Number`. This will try to match first with the string with parentheses and if it can't it will try the short form.
Also the pattern should be: `Number\(s\)|Number`
The unrecognized escape error message comes because if you want this pattern written as a string literal you must escape the backslash signs: `"Number\\(s\\)|Number"`.

Comment: It would be very nice to have some explanations for -1! The answer was tested before posting and it was working!